# Validating response text in a Google Form with Regex in Google App Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to validate the response text with Regex, being aware that it can be done manually (https://www.labnol.org/internet/regular-expressions-forms/28380/).

However, as we are building the forms with Google App Script, I am trying to use FormApp.createTextValidation() to construct the validation needed. There are many different methods available (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder), but they seems to be all pre-set. As we may have very specific validation formats, we need to write our own regex to validate the response. Is that possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second link applies to spreadsheets, not to forms. Instead of that link you have to look into [Class TextValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder), more specifically

- requireTextContainsPattern(pattern)
- requireTextDoesNotContainPattern(pattern)
- requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(pattern)

Comment: This is the perfect answer! I originally thought pattern has to be exact match, but it turns out to accept regex! Thanks a lot!